# Convergence of Discretized Process with infinite variation.

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, probability-limit-theorems

This question is related to Theorem IX.7.28 in J. Jacod and A. Shiryaev's Limit Theorems for Stochstic Processes (2013).

Let our discretized process be
\begin{align}
 X^n_t = \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \left(W_{\frac{i}{n}} - W_{\frac{i-2}{n}}\right),
\end{align}
where $W$ is a standard Wiener process.
My intuition says that it would converge stably in law to $2W$, i.e.,
\begin{align}
X^n \xrightarrow{\mathcal{L}-s} 2W.
\end{align}
But I'm not sure it is ok to apply Theorem IX.7.28 to show this, because the predictable part (denote it as $B^n_t$) converges to Wiener process itself which has "infinite variation":
\begin{align}
B^n_t &:= \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \mathbb{E}_{\frac{i-1}{n}} \left[ W_{\frac{i}{n}} - W_{\frac{i-2}{n}} \right]  \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \left(W_{\frac{i-1}{n}} - W_{\frac{i-2}{n}}\right)  \\
&= W_{\frac{[(n-1)t]}{n}} \xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} W_t,
\end{align}
while Jacod and Shiryaev's theorem says that $B^n_t$ should converge to a predictable "finite variation" process $B_t$.
So how can I show this?

**Here is a Theorem.**

Without considering the truncation function or jumps of $X$, the theorem says:

> **IX.7.28 Theorem.** For every càdlàg process $X$, we use the following notation:
> \begin{align*}
> X_t^n = X_{[nt]/n},\qquad\qquad \Delta_i^n X = X_{i/n} - X_{(i-1)/n} = \Delta X^n_{i/n},
> \end{align*}
> We also consider the discretized process of the form
> \begin{align*}
> X_t^n = \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \chi_i^n,
> \end{align*}
> where each $\chi_i^n$ is $\mathcal{F}_{i/n}$-measurable.
> Assume that each $\chi_i^n$ is square-integrable, and $X$ is a continuous and $\mathbb{E}[|X_t|^2] < \infty$ for all $t$ with the canonical decomposition $X_t = B_t + M_t$ where $B_t$ is predictable finite variation process and $M_t$ is square-integrable local martingale.
>
> Suppose also that for all $t>0$ and all uniformly integrable martingale $N$ which are orthogonal to $X$ we have
> \begin{align*}
> \sup_t \left| \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \mathbb{E} _{\frac{i-1}{n}}[\chi_i^n] - B_t \right| &\xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} 0,  \\
> \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \mathbb{V}_{\frac{i-1}{n}}[\chi_i^n] &\xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} \langle M, M \rangle_t + \langle w \cdot W', w \cdot W' \rangle_t \\
> \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \mathbb{E}_{\frac{i-1}{n}}[\chi_i^n \Delta_i^n M] &\xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} \langle M, M \rangle_t,  \\
> \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \mathbb{E}_{\frac{i-1}{n}}[\chi_i^n \Delta_i^n N] &\xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} 0.
> \end{align*}
> Then there is a very good canonical Wiener extension of $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \{\mathcal{F}_t\}, \mathbb{P})$ with Wiener process $W'$ and a continuous $X$-biased $\mathcal{F}$-progressive conditional martingale PII $X'$ on this extension such that
> \begin{align*}
> X^n \xrightarrow{\mathcal{L}-s} X' = X + w \cdot W',
> \end{align*}
> where $w \cdot W' = \int w\,dW'$  and $w$ is a predictable process.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!